# git Exlude files without pattern (especionally .)

Tags: git, gitignore

is it possible to add files that match "pattern" to the gitignore?
The problem is that the custom build system creates executables without containing a point, so I wanted to exclude them, but neither  `!*.*` nor `[^\.]*` worked (the latter because git does not support regex, the fore because it overrode the gitignore in the project root folder).
Are there any other ways to exclude given pattern?

Comment: What are the names of the executables like? Are they fixed? Are they all in a certain directory?

Comment: the names of the executables is fixed and they are all in one directionary
e.g PATH/TO/FOLDER/foo.cpp > PATH/TO/FOLDER/foo. The gitignore is in that folder and it would be possible to add all manually, but that is a lot of work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these 2 lines to your root `.gitignore`

```
<executable_directory>/*
!<executable_directory>/*.*
```

You can leave out `<executable_directory>/` if you put the `.gitignore` in that directory.

It will ignore everything in that directory except the files with `.`

Comment: problem with this solution is that it overrides all settings from the project-wide gitignore, e.g. `foo.cpp~` will appear again, although `*~` was in the project-wide gitignore

Comment: Add those settings AFTER the 2 lines above